# parentNode.removeChild not removing element, why?

Tags: javascript

After many changes and attempts, I still can't understand why this is not working. The Process function is designed to remove the paragraph with the "def" class. It is being executed after the body is loaded, and the getElementsByClassName method is able to find it, as the alert function demonstrates, but for some reason It can't be removed, Why?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript">

function Process()
{
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('def');

var elem = elements[0];
alert(elem.className);
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="Process();">
<h1>This is a title</h1>
<p>Sample Paragraph</p>
<p>This should not be interpreted by the Wiki</p>
<p class="def"><p id="definition">Text</p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<p class="def">` does actually get remove. The reason `<p id="definition">Text</p>` stays is because it is invalid to put `p` tags inside of `p` tags. `<p id="definition">` gets removed from `<p class="def">` by the DOM parser and they become sibling elements.

See the [W3C section on the `p` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) for what tags are not permitted inside of `p` tags.

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).

Instead of using

```
<p class="def"><p id="definition">Text</p></p>
```

Try using

```
<p class="def"><span id="definition">Text</span></p>
```

Comment: So, in the nested paragraphs case, the only way to remove both paragraphs is removing the inner paragraph and later the outer one? Where can I find more information about why they become sibling elements? I didn't know anything about that matter...

Comment: @BirdyBiker You can't actually put a `p` tag within a `p` tag. It's invalid, and the browser will (most-likely) try to resolve the issue by closing the open `p` tag to start the new one. I've added a link in my answer to the specification that says what tags are not permitted with `p` tags.

Comment: Ok, I think have understood the issue. In sum: it couldn't be removed that way because, as a consecuence of being an invalid piece of HTML code, the "inner paragraph" has never been interpreted as a child element. Am I wroing? :)